# Build a Docker image on top of CodeBuild Docker Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

As AWS CodeBuild provides "Docker" curated images (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref.html),
I'd like to reuse one of those to build my custom CodeBuild Image (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html).

I don't know the CodeBuild Registry Url.
How to reference those images (FROM) ?

I could rebuild myself the image I need (https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images) and host it in a private ECR but it's wasting time and storage.

Answer (score 2):

CodeBuild's internal Docker repository used for Curated Images is not publicly accessible. You should build your own base image from the [official Dockerfiles](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images).

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CodeBuild provides also a console where you can use these images. I think they use Amazon EC2 Repository to provide these internally, like the [one you can use](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecr/). but there isn't a public registry (or I already haven't found).

You can find these images to create Docker machines using the build spec defined by Amazon

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this public image but is not official:

https://hub.docker.com/r/sandorzelei/aws-codebuild/

So you can use it as follows:

```
FROM sandorzelei/aws-codebuild
```